# Python List - wierd behaviour

Tags: list

I was trying to solve the 3Sum problem in leetcode. but I observed python lists behaving different during the end of loop statement.

```
def threeSum(nums):
    n=len(nums)
    sum = {}
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if i != j:
                key = nums[i]+nums[j]
                if key not in sum:
                    sum[key] = [nums[i],nums[j]]
    for i in range(n):
        if -nums[i] in sum:
            temp = sum[-nums[i]]
            temp.append(nums[i])
            if(len(temp)<=3):
                result.append(temp)
                print(result)
    print("at the end of loop")
    print(result)
    return "result printed"

nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
print(threeSum(nums))
```

For the above function I got the output as

```
[[-1, 2, -1]]
[[-1, 2, -1], [-1, 1, 0]]
[[-1, 2, -1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1]]
[[-1, 2, -1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]
at the end of loop
[[-1, 2, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]
result printed
```

From the output you can see that during the last iteration of the loop the `result` List variable contains the value `[[-1, 2, -1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]` but when I print the same `result` at the end of the loop it is printed as `[[-1, 2, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]` , the first element in List is changed.

How do you explain this? Am I missing something in the understanding of Python Lists?

**P.S : Please ignore the solution of 3Sum problem, I already found another way to solve it, my question is regarding the Python List only**

Comment: Your logic has some flaw - try to run the code in http://www.pythontutor.com/ and pay attention to step 120-122.  It will show you why.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, List is reference value. In your code, you refer to sum[1] 2 times. Both of 2 times return to the same List instance. That's why after the 2nd time, that List instance is appended 1 more number

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by two issues:

- `if(len(temp)<=3):` will prevent printing the final result due to the length constraint
- python lists are mutable and they can be modified from different places if the same object is referenced

In your case, at fourth iteration `result[0]` and `temp` will reference the same object. This is why result gets modified even it was not apparently touched. It was changed due to the change of temp variable. You can check this using additional prints to highlight current iteration, result and object ids.

```
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
    print(result)
    if -nums[i] in sum:
        temp = sum[-nums[i]]
        temp.append(nums[i])
        if(len(temp)<=3):
            result.append(temp)
            print(result)
        print(id(result[0]))
        print(id(temp))
print("at the end of loop")
print(result)
return "result printed"
```